# How can i style content projected html elements?

Tags: angular

I have component `parent` in which i am projecting input.So in my `app.component.html` file i have

```
<app-parent>
  <input />
</app-parent>
```

i want for example to add red border on my input then if i write in `app.component.css`

```
input {
  border: 2px solid red !important;
}
```

it will apply red border on that input.

But i want to style this input in the `parent components css`

So if i write there - in `parent.component.css` file

```
input {
  border: 2px solid red !important;
}
```

my input does not get red border.

Why is that ?

How can i do this ?

Here is also stackblitz example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fganoq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

Comment: But your stackblitz does work - can't see the problem.

Comment: @AviadP it does not work.the input is not red.

Comment: That's because you commented out the style, look at your css file

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, you want the containing component to be able to style content that was projected INTO it - let me think more about it

Comment: On second thought, I think I'll take your advice, but only with regards to this question.

Comment: i am glad to hear that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can style non-owned content by using the ng-deep pseudo-selector:

```
:host ::ng-deep input {
     border: 2px solid red;
}
```

note that you should always prefix styles that use ng-deep with the :host prefix to prevent style from leaking out of your component.

Comment: Manhattan Thanks for the answer. Btw what does ::ng-deep mean ?

Comment: this disables view encapsulation for the righthand style selector. it's acutally kind of deprecated, but to date, angular does not provide an alternative. see also https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep